# Combobox с CheckBox,как можно сделать?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, combobox

Необходимо сделать такой элемент,при помощи каких средств это делается[image: введите сюда описание изображения]?

Comment: Суть вопроса не понятна. Что именно не получается?

Comment: `ListCheckBox` - вот и всё

Comment: @АндрейNOP Чтобы на фоне combox был checkBox

Comment: И что должно отображаться при выборе каждого из пунктов в выпадающем списке?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Должно обрабатываться события click и все.Мне сейчас нужно сделать,чтобы именно на фоне был работающий checkBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этого можно добиться изменением шаблона. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по ComboBox в дизайнере и выберите "Edit Template" - "Edit a Copy...", студия добавит вам разметку стиля контрола. Найдите в ней описание шаблона `<Setter Property="Template">`, а в нем `ContentPresenter` с `Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"` - это именно то место, где выводится выбранная из выпадающего списка строчка. Удалите этот `ContentPresenter` и вместо него разместите `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
```

Получается вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]