# Как переопределить шаблон в WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Мне нужно изменить цвет в ComboBox WPF. Для этого я пытаюсь переопределить шаблон. Но если я сделаю это

```
<ComboBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome Color="Red"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
</ComboBox.Template>
```

Оно просто создает красный квадраткоторый ничего не делает. Все остальные свойства ComboBox потеряны.  Как переопределить шаблон, чтобы изменить цвет и сохранить свойства ComboBox?

Comment: Шаблон надо править как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820613/218063 в вашем, понятно, много чего не хватает

Comment: @АндрейNOP а одно свойство нельзя менять без влезания во весь шаблон?

Comment: Нельзя, шаблон можно переопределять только полностью

Comment: @АндрейNOP а стиль можно частично?Хотя там наверное нельзя компоненты визуального дерева переопределять

Comment: У стиля можно отдельные свойства, но вам это ничего не даст. Потому что шаблон целиком это одно свойство